# How to get the timespan between two time in xp using C#

Tags: c#, timespan

I am developing the C# windows application which needs to be run in windows XP. However the timespan concept is working in windows 7 and later versions the XP is not supporting it.

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1[2, 1].Value.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1[2, 0].Value.ToString()));
```

While running the value of diff in 7 and 8 the span time.

But in XP it shows 00:00.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _not supporting_? You mean not working? Any exception or error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Label displaying Timespan disappearing in XP but not in newer Windows versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958767/label-displaying-timespan-disappearing-in-xp-but-not-in-newer-windows-versions)

Comment: I just ran the application in XP it showed 00:00 instead of time span.

Comment: Could you please give examples of the values you are passing to the parse functions

Comment: Windows XP has nothing to do with it. You're running your code against CLR. If you've got .NET installed on your Win XP and the app is running, then there's no such thing as "not supporting it"

Answer (score 1):

Provide a format mask when displaying the time of the TimeSpan:

```
diff.ToString("mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stopwatch like that:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
//do something
sw.Stop();

MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```